XSS Risks in XML Transfer With HTTPS
I have been checking lots of recourses but still have problems finding my answer, so I will ask it directly:
I have a situation in my website where

I make an API call and in response I get HTML document
Then I add some data to this HTML document, create an XML from it and send the XML with API
(I do not show these files anywhere e.g. in the DOM, nor use it in any other ways on the client-side)

What are the risks of XSS attacks in this process? Do I need to do encode/decode or sanitization or both? Should I do it for the HTML response or the created XML? Should this be done on client-side or server-side?

XSS Filter Evasion Cheat Sheet and XML External Entity Prevention Cheat Sheet. If protocol is not https then the risk is high I believe.

@LMC The protocol IS https

Make call using HTTPS (not HTTP).  HTTPS is secure because it is encrypted and cannot be decrypted.
